# BuildUrlFromExpressionForAreas does not generate restful URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have a controller action that takes an id as a parameter.  The restful way to call this is:  /Controller/Action/id, and if I use an ActionLink helper (below), the URL is generated correctly.

```
Html.ActionLink(linkText, action, controller, new { id = myid })
```

However, I need to get the url to open the page in a new window.  I tried using BuildUrlFromExpressionForAreas, but it gives me a url in the following format: /Controller/Action?id=myid.

```
Html.BuildUrlFromExpressionForAreas<MyController>(t => t.Action(myid))
```

This doesn't work - I get the following exception:

The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Guid' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Resume(System.Guid)'

Is there another helper method I should use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully, there's a better approach, but in the mean time, here's my solution:

1 - Add "action-link" class to action links

> Html.ActionLink(linkText, action,
>   controller, new { id = myid }, new {
>   @class='action-link'})

2 - Use jquery to get the generated url and bind it to the click event and set href to #

```
       $(document).ready(function () {
           $(".action-link").each(
               function (index, el) {
                   var url = $(this).attr("href");
                   $(this).attr("href", "#").bind("click",
                       function () {
                           var options = "resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,status=no,menubar=no";
                           window.open(url, "Interview", options, true);
                       });
               }
           );
       });
```